# Can I create a Kivy GUI for my Django Web App?

Tags: python, django, kivy

I have a Django web app which currently uses HTML templates with CSS styling. Fairly typical for a Django app. I've been looking to create a more animated GUI for this app and was looking to Kivy to do this. Is it possible to combine these two frameworks to coexist in the same app?

Comment: If you want a more animated front-end for your Web app I would suggest using a javascript framework (Vue, React, Angular, ect.), instead of Kivy. You can use django (REST) for the back-end stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Django Serializing, Where you can connect asynchronously with Django models. As per my understanding you want use Django models to fetch data right? Django Serializing will convert models into required format xml, json